# Dynamic create a button in dynamic page

Tags: c#, wpf

In the WPF,

I want to create dynamic frame, page, and button. The following is the code,

```
private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame frm = new Frame();
    Grid.SetRow(frm, 0);
    Grid.SetColumn(frm, 0);

    Page page = new Page();
    frm.Navigate(page);

    Button btn = new Button();
    Grid pageGrid = new Grid();
    pageGrid.Children.Add(btn);

    page.Content = pageGrid;
}
```

the button is created on page, page is created on frame and frame is created on window.

But this code does not have any item control in it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `Content` of the window to the `Frame` or add it to some panel of the window to be able to see the `Frame`:

```
private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame frm = new Frame();
    Grid.SetRow(frm, 0);
    Grid.SetColumn(frm, 0);

    Page page = new Page();
    frm.Navigate(page);

    Button btn = new Button();
    Grid pageGrid = new Grid();
    pageGrid.Children.Add(btn);

    page.Content = pageGrid;

    Content = frm; //or mainGrid.Children.Add(frm);
}
```

Comment: other question is my basegrid is 3 rows, I want to put the frame in row 0, how do I impletement?

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have another issue.